# How to find out if a file exists in Perl

Tags: perl

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my @arr = ('/usr/test/test.*.con');
my $result = FileExists(\@arr);

print $result;

sub FileExists {
    my $param = shift;
    foreach my $file (@{$param}) {
        print $file;
        if (-e $file) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It returns 0. But I want to find all wild characters too... How can I solve this?

Comment: I don't know if you're in Windows or Unix, but in Unix shell normally handles wildcard expansion. Thus, if you run `myprog.pl *.txt`, your program will see a list of .txt files in the directory if there are any. To avoid that expansion, you need to enclose the argument in quotes: `myprog.pl "*.txt"`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`-e` can't handle file globs. Change this line

```
my @arr = ('/usr/test/test.*.con');
```

to

```
my @arr = glob('/usr/test/test.*.con');
```

To expand the glob pattern first and then check the matched files for existence. However, since *glob* will only return existing files matching the pattern, all the files will exist anyway.

Comment: Perhaps what they'll want to do then is just check to see if glob produces any results at all, i.e.: my @arr = glob(...); print "Yes" if @arr > 0;

Comment: Because glob implements shell expansion rules it can in some cases return files that don't exist. For example `glob('no{file,where}')` returns two items and neither exist on my file system.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use glob() to get the file list.

Also, I'm not sure why you are passing the array as a reference, when subroutines take an array by default.  You could much more easily write it like this:

```
my @arr = (...);
my $result = FileExists(@arr);

sub FileExists {
    foreach my $file (@_) {
        ...
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to handle glob patterns, use the [`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) operator to expand them. Then test all the paths, store the results in a hash, and return the hash.

```
sub FileExists {
    my @param = map glob($_) => @{ shift @_ };

    my %exists;
    foreach my $file (@param) {
      print $file, "\n";
      $exists{$file} = -e $file;
    }

    wantarray ? %exists : \%exists;
}
```

Then say you use it as in

```
use Data::Dumper;

my @arr = ('/tmp/test/test.*.con', '/usr/bin/a.txt');
my $result = FileExists(\@arr);

$Data::Dumper::Indent = $Data::Dumper::Terse = 1;
print Dumper $result;
```

Sample run:

```
$ ls /tmp/test
test.1.con  test.2.con  test.3.con

$ ./prog.pl 
/tmp/test/test.1.con
/tmp/test/test.2.con
/tmp/test/test.3.con
/usr/bin/a.txt
{
  '/tmp/test/test.3.con' => 1,
  '/tmp/test/test.1.con' => 1,
  '/usr/bin/a.txt' => undef,
  '/tmp/test/test.2.con' => 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using glob() you would have the shell expansion, and files using shell wildcards can be retrieved, as the others have pointed out.

And just in case you find it useful, a bit more concise function for 'all_files_exist' could be

```
sub all_files_exist {
   # returns 1 if all files exist and 0 if the number of missing files (!-e) 
   # captured with grep is > 0.
   # This method expect an array_ref as first and only argument

   my $files=shift; 
   return (grep {!-e $_} @$files)>0?  0 : 1; 
}

sub non_existing_files {
   # or you can capture which ones fail, and print with 
   # print join("\n", @(non_existing_files($files)))
   my $files = shift;
   return [grep {!-e $_} @$files]
}
```