# How to support the searching file based on regular expression

Tags: regex, perl

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406191/how-to-find-the-file-exists-in-perl)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my @arr = ('/usr/test/test-[\d.*].*.con');
```

How to support the searching file based on regular expression

Comment: can you elaborate your question?

Comment: The character class `[\d.*]` matches any digit, dot, or asterisk. What do you really want to match after `test-`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your question, here's one way to do it: use `glob` to find all files in the directory and `grep` to filter them.

```
my $dir = '/usr/test';
my @files = grep { /REGEX_HERE/ } glob("$dir/*");
```

Comment: i cant defind  the dir because i am getting full string . so how can i change this part

Comment: @Tree Sorry, I'm not understanding your question. Perhaps you can clarify.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [File::Find](http://search.cpan.org/~nwclark/perl-5.8.5/lib/File/Find.pm) for doing exactly this.

```
use File::Find;

my @files = ();
find( sub {/test-[\d.*].*.con/ && push @files, $File::Find::name}, '/usr/test' );

print foreach (@files);
```